# Should smoke/steam ever be coming from my brand new HP CP-1215 Laser Jet printer while printing?

Tags: laser-printer

Should smoke/steam ever be coming from my brand new HP CP-1215 Laser Jet printer while printing, given that there are hot parts internally?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is definitely not a standard operating thing.  **Unplug the printer ASAP**, and **bring it back** to the store where you bought it from (and hope they give you a new one).  This seems like a very serious safety issue.  I have never personally seen a laser printer "smoke" or produce "steam" during operation.  Furthermore, I have a similar model printer, which has not done anything like that from day one.

**For your own personal safety**, make sure you stay far away from any stray gasses/smoke/steam that has been emitted from the printer, as [these are known toxins](http://www.news.qut.edu.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/News.woa/wa/goNewsPage?newsEventID=13495).

Comment: It could be steam off damp paper stock...

Comment: @Matt Damp paper is going to do nothing good for the quality of output or the printer.

Comment: You're bang on the button there ;)

Comment: @Matt Jenkins: Sounds like an answer which seems like it should be posted as one.

Comment: @C.W.Joleman II yes but it all comes under the heading of this answer... even if it's 'just' damp paper it's still not a good idea to use it.  And if the paper's damp, that doesn't say much for the environment the printer's in, so I would be inclined to unplug it anyway ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same thing with my Brother HL1212W. It has no smell, which indicates that it's steam from moist paper.

To confirm this, you can print again using the same sheets (which should be drier after going through the printer), and the steam should be reduced or totally gone.

> If steam or vapor is visible when the product prints, immediately reprint the print job on the same piece of paper. There might be no vapor or less vapor visible while reprinting.
> https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01617122

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).